# yfR：Error in download.Error in `vec_slice()`: ! `x` must be a vector, not NULL

Tags: r, quantmod

I am sure I have installed the latest packages include "quantomd":(devtools::install_github("joshuaulrich/quantmod", ref = "358-getsymbols-new.session"))
But still fail to use yfR.I realized that the problem may be in the "quantmod" . When I use the functions of "quantmod" to get data, it will also report an error.

About fyR:

```
my_ticker <- 'FB'
first_date <- Sys.Date() - 30
last_date <- Sys.Date()
df_yf <- yf_get(tickers = my_ticker, first_date = first_date, last_date = last_date)
```

── Running yfR for 1 stocks | 2022-04-06 --> 2022-05-06 (30 days) ──

ℹ Downloading data for benchmark ticker ^GSPC
ℹ (1/1) Fetching data for FB
!       - not cached
✖       - error in download..
ℹ Binding price data
Error in `vec_slice()`:
! `x` must be a vector, not NULL.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: `ticker`.
2: Unknown or uninitialised column: `threshold_decision`.
3: Unknown or uninitialised column: `ticker`.
4: Unknown or uninitialised column: `price_adjusted`.
####################################################

> rlang::last_error()
> <error/vctrs_error_scalar_type>
> Error in `vec_slice()`:
> ! `x` must be a vector, not NULL.

---

Backtrace:

1. yfR::yf_get(tickers = my_ticker, first_date = first_date, last_date = last_date)
2. yfR:::calc_ret(...)
3. dplyr::lag(P)
4. vctrs::vec_slice(inputs$x, seq_len(xlen - n))
   Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
   ##############################################

> rlang::last_trace()
> <error/vctrs_error_scalar_type>
> Error in `vec_slice()`:
> ! `x` must be a vector, not NULL.

---

Backtrace:
▆

1. ├─yfR::yf_get(tickers = my_ticker, first_date = first_date, last_date = last_date)
2. │ └─yfR:::calc_ret(...)
3. │   └─dplyr::lag(P)
4. │     ├─vctrs::vec_c(...)
5. │     └─vctrs::vec_slice(inputs$x, seq_len(xlen - n))
6. └─vctrs:::stop_scalar_type(`<fn>`(NULL), "x", `<env>`)
7. └─vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)
8. ```
   └─rlang::abort(message, class = c(class, "vctrs_error"), ..., call = vctrs_error_call(call))
   ```

About quantmod：

> getSymbols("AAPL", src = "yahoo")    # from yahoo financ
> Warning: AAPL download failed; trying again.
> Error in getSymbols.yahoo(Symbols = "AAPL", env = , verbose = FALSE,  :
> Unable to import “AAPL”.
> AAPL download failed after two attempts. Error message:
> Timeout was reached: [query2.finance.yahoo.com] Operation timed out after 10005 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received

> getSymbols("AAPL", src = "yahoo")    # from yahoo financ
> Warning: AAPL download failed; trying again.
> Error in getSymbols.yahoo(Symbols = "AAPL", env = , verbose = FALSE,  :
> Unable to import “AAPL”.
> AAPL download failed after two attempts. Error message:
> HTTP error 403.

Comment: The latest quantmod version is on cran (version 0.4.20), so you can just `update.packages` or `install.packages`. Or use the update / install via Rstudio.

Running your code does not generate any errors on my side. Try again after a few minutes.

Comment: I've tried updating the quantmod package, but I'm still failing, which seems to be because I don't have access to yahoo. I checked the script of the 'quantmod', he accessed:http://query2.finance.yahoo.com, the problem is that I can't access:http://query2.finance.yahoo.com.Then I checked the engineer's answer: From November 1, 2021, users will not be able to use Yahoo's products and services from mainland China. This does not affect Yahoo's products and services elsewhere in the world. We thank you for your continued support.

Comment: In addition, I have an unkind request, I don't know if you could help me download the data set, the code that can be executed to get the data is:                                                  library(BatchGetSymbols)  # sp500 symbols   symbols <- c("AAPL", "T")    prices <- BatchGetSymbols(symbols, first.date = as.Date("1990-01-01"))   or      library(yfR)                                                                                                                    my_ticker <- c('AAPL', 'T')   df_yf_multiple <- yf_get(tickers = my_ticker, first_date= as.Date("1990-01-01"))

Comment: Anyway, I am very grateful to you for answering my confusion, if you can help me, Please send the data to my email: wangcongyuan@gamil.com or vitally@hdu.edu.cn,Thanks!

Comment: Try using [tiingo](https://api.tiingo.com/). Their end of day data is very good. Once you have the api you can use quantmod to get access to the data.